# Why SharePoint can't activate a dependency feature, while upgrading a feature?

Tags: feature-activation, feature-upgrade, feature-dependency

This question is regarding dependency feature activation, while upgrading a feature to latest version.

Suppose, There is a feature called MasterFeature_0_0_0_0 and it is being upgraded to MasterFeature_1_0_0_0. This MasterFeature_X_X_X_X is depended on subfeature_0_0_0_0. SubFeature_0_0_0_0 is visible feature.

As per *MSDN documentation*( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee538968(v=office.14).aspx ), when the subfeature is not visible, custom code needs to be written for in UPgrading event to do that.

Ask: **why do default upgradation infrastructure can activate a hidden feature and cant' activate a visible feature?**

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you have to do a deploy (install, upgrade, enable/disable features, and so on) you want do that with a Powershell script written before.

In this way you will be able to check your feature (hidden or not), disable it (if you can), upgrade, and etc.

Comment: salvatore, pls reread the question. It looks you misunderstood the question.